# What type of cable to use to extend Kinect cable?

Tags: kinect

I just got a Kinect and I have a wall mounted TV with the wires running behind the wall.  I really want to hide the wires for the Kinect behind my wall but MS sure did not make it easy with the weird cable setup.

The way I see it is I have 3 options:
- Buy the overpriced "official" extension cable that is only 10 feet long.
- Buy a 16 foot standard USB 2.0 extension cable, Male to Female with buffer ([like this one](https://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=103&cp_id=10303&cs_id=1030312&p_id=2779&seq=1&format=2&style=))
- Buy a super cheap 15 foot simple USB 2.0 extension cable, Male to Female ([like this](https://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=103&cp_id=10303&cs_id=1030304&p_id=5435&seq=1&format=2&style=))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of the comments, on the provided links, they all should work extending the Kinect cable.

Super cheap cable:

> Had to wait until the kids opened the Kinect at xmas and was nervous this wouldn't work as the "official" Kinect cables are ridiculously overpriced. But this cable with it's extra length I needed to hook this from XBOX to Kinect worked flawlessely.

Standard cable:

> For people people who are wondering, this cable works great with the Kinect!

So it's pretty much up to how much you're willing to spend, as they all should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

On one of the [Major Nelson Podcasts](http://majornelson.com/podcast/) somebody mentioned that you could extend the Kinect cable with a standard USB cable.  They warned that the information Kinect is sending to the Xbox is very time sensitive so not to use too long of an extension.